# Best way of storing and retrieving files - BaaS or S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, data-storage, parse-platform

We are facing the following dilemma:

Our mobile client application will be user-authenticating through a BaaS (Backend-as-a-Service) and will then need to send a file to the cloud - specifically an Amazon EC2 server where the main processing will take place. Since the time of processing of the file might take place later, there is a need to store the files (and there is also a prospect of keeping an archive of them for future use by the users). The question is what would you suggest as the preferred way from the following:
a) send the file to the EC2 server directly which will then issue an Amazon S3 request to save the file there
OR
b) store the file to the BaaS (which in our case is parse.com which uses S3 as its data-storage) and retrieve it later by the EC2 server

The cost of transferring a file from EC2 to S3 and inverse is 0 as long as both are on the same region which in both a) and b) cases is true. The problem is that there is a need for mapping each user to the files that he has access to and a) and b) differ a lot in this case.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are sending file to EC2 - EC2 is processing it and saving it to S3 or it is just saving it to S3 ??.I used a very easy way of transferring data from Ec2 to S3. i.e. s3fuse :- you can basically mount EC2 drive with S3 , so when you store something on EC2, it will automatically be stored in S3 also. Might be handy for you.

Comment: One of the EC2 servers will initially be storing the file to S3 until the one of the (EC2) worker-servers has enough free resources to retrieve it and process it.

Comment: Great, thats exactly what we are doing. So, I would highly recommend using s3fuse, and mount both the instances. This way, you will just have to save file on your first EC2 instance and it will be available on s3 as well as worker-server. And also , mount worker-serve processed file folder with s3 processed file folder (or bucket).I would like to know more about user specific file permission. Even though you can set permissions for file access in s3 , but i cannot recommend anything unless you give more details.

Comment: We were actually thinking of applying the user permissions through parse.com which we already use for client authentication. The user will be registering the reference to the file in parse.com (and then upload the file itself to EC2/S3), so EC2 will thus be knowing which file belongs to whom.

Comment: Alright, so only thing which you will have to do is after processing the file, send the details ( file name, URI.. etc) back to parse.com and save it. you will not be dealing with file upload and retrieval from/by parse.com !

Comment: Actually the original question was referring to this particular subject: if we are going to use parse.com additionally for file upload and retrieval or only as middle-ware for user authentication and file-permissions registration. For the time being, we are designing the system with the latter approach, so the answer to your last comment is yes.

Comment: Great, I guess thats a good way to do it. even we have a server xyz.com, which uploads file to ec2 ( mounted with s3), and a task is created , which is read by ec2 controller, detect the free resources , allocate the job, process the file and save it back to s3 mounted drive . works pretty good for us.